# Where does AppCompat set the actionbar/toolbar?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

The boilerplate that Android Studio generates creates a style that extends `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Somehow, this adds an actionbar/toolbar at the top of all my activities.

How does this happen? Where is the bar defined? It's nowhere in the layouts.

Comment: what do you mean by defined? If you want to see some implementation code, go in your styles.xml, click on Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar to select it, right click, then Go to, then Implementation. You'll see some implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Android studio inflates custom Views or ViewGroups they have already defined, most of these you cannot see because they are private classes.

Here is an example of how you would do this in code.

```
class Test extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {


    public Test(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initTestView(null);
    }

    public Test(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initTestView(attrs);
    }

    public Test(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initTestView(attrs);
    }

    public void initTestView(AttributeSet as) {
        if (as != null) {
            TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(as, R.styleable.Test);

            String textOverride = ta.getString(R.styleable.Test_override);
            ta.recycle();

            setText("Test: " + textOverride);
        }
    }

}
```

Then you would define a styleable in the `app/src/main/res/values/attr.xml`

```
<declare-styleable name="Test">
    <attr name="override" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Now when Android inflates this, it can see your custom class as well as attributes to construct it with. If you were to add this to a layout it would automatically generate an example view of my code. This is the same as Androids core styled Views/ViewGroups and they will oftentimes have default values or visible representations of these class as they are inflated and attached to their parent views.

To make it perfectly clear, when you add an Android View into your layout, let's say for simplicity .

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/hello"
  android:text="@string/greeting"/>
```

The class for TextView is doing similar stuff to my examples `initTestView` method, by grabbing its typed properties (text, id) and populating the Views or values it has internally. It is, at its core, how Android glues xml values to their class representations.

Comment: "The bar is defined in an already generated android style", that's exactly my question, how is the style.xml adding a bar to my activity...

I know how to remove it, thanks.

Comment: Its inflated by android automatically and populated. As part of the build process Android generates R classes as well as pulls in styled components that their appcompat library uses. This can include custom Views or Viewgroups that are only visible to Android (i.e. private classes). Some of the code you cannot see, but if you want a close approximation for whats going on play with the newer appCompat Toolbar class.

Comment: The latest edit is starting to make more sense :) But I'm still not clear on something, in your example, I would need to add <Test> to my layout for it to be inflated and shown in the "Design" tab in Android Studio, but I never did this with the toolbar that gets added as part of AppCompat :/

Comment: Yes, but its the same principle. Adding <android.whatever.path.ActionBar> does exactly the same thing as my example you just can't see the exposed class.

Comment: Also updated the answer one last time illustrating the point with a TextView

Comment: Thanks. Let's say I have some ActivityA.java & LayoutA.xml and I didn't add the <Test> component, neither to the layout nor the java class. What would I need to modify in the styles.xml/layout/theme to automatically add the <Test> component to my activity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186022/discussion-between-chris-sullivan-and-danish-khan).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Chris Sullivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6359929/chris-sullivan) we figured out what was going on. This is an estimated guess.

It turns out that using the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` style/theme just adds some type top margin to all activities and fills them with the primary color. This makes it look in the Android editor as if there's an app bar/toolbar/action bar, but it's just smoke and mirrors.

The actual app bar is added at runtime by AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score -1):

This is defined in the styles xml. Your apptheme extends from it. If you want it to be gone you can extend another style for example Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: But how can you define an actionbar from styles.xml? Shouldn't this be in a layout.xml?

Comment: you create a menu.xml file in the res and use the onCreateOptionsMenu callback in the activity to inflate it

Comment: It is possible to define it in your layout, but then you should use a toolbar and set that as the actionbar in onCreate with the setSupportActionbar method, but i recommend the onCreateOptions menu if you don't need to customize alot

Comment: I know how to define it from code. My question is, how is this placed in my view and displayed in the Android Studio editor without any of this code running and just by adding a theme?

Comment: i would check references/call hierarchy on the onCreateOptionsMenu callback and look inside the android framework if you want to know that. I'm not sure when and how android does that. Why do you even need to know this?

Comment: I don't mean how the Android framework does this, but how is importing a single theme like AppCompat doing this to my layout. I thought UI components need to be declared in the layout.xml or be added through code. But since the code hasn't run yet and I haven't manually added the app bar myself, how is this visible from Android Studio. Can you define UI components in styles.xml?

Comment: > Can you define UI components in styles.xml?
partially, I will update my code example.